# How to split array in Julia like in Python?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to do this :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(a[:2])
```

The output is

```
[1, 2]
```

How can I do the same things in Julia? But my `a` is of type : Array{Array{Float64,1},1}

Comment: Exactly the same way, just with a 1 in front of the colon (1:2 instead of :2)?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume you have:

```
julia> x = [[i] for i in 1.0:5.0]
5-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0]
 [2.0]
 [3.0]
 [4.0]
 [5.0]
```

(this is an equivalent of you have written above but with the types you request).

You can slice `x` by passing the first and the last index of the slice. Both lower and upper bound will be included (also note that Julia uses 1-based indexing):

```
julia> x[1:2]
2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0]
 [2.0]

julia> x[2:4]
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [2.0]
 [3.0]
 [4.0]
```

You can use `end` to indicate end of your collection:

```
julia> x[3:end]
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [3.0]
 [4.0]
 [5.0]
```

The above operations created a new vector. If you prefer to have a view then write:

```
julia> @view x[2:4]
3-element view(::Array{Array{Float64,1},1}, 2:4) with eltype Array{Float64,1}:
 [2.0]
 [3.0]
 [4.0]
```

or

```
julia> view(x, 2:4)
3-element view(::Array{Array{Float64,1},1}, 2:4) with eltype Array{Float64,1}:
 [2.0]
 [3.0]
 [4.0]
```

The difference is that with `@view` macro you can still use `end`, e.g. `@view x[2:end]`, but `view` function does not support it.